# Why is it called onBlur?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript has an event called onBlur that fires when a control loses focus. My question is: Why is it called that? Wouldn't all of our lives be easier if it was called OnFocusLost?

Comment: If you use a camera and look at something, you're focusing on it. By proxy, everything else is "blurred", is it not? Besides, my carpel tunnel doesn't like typing `OnFocusLost`.

Comment: Probably because blurred means out of focus?

Comment: The opposite of "to focus" is "to blur."

Comment: Note that IE has a similar event called [onfocusout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755052/in-web-browser-whats-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onfocusout)

Comment: .net WinForms calls the event .Leave and IMO that's a much better design. I've been porting a UI component and only five days into the job have I understood what this "blur" event does. The name IS cute but its not descriptive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would imagine it is called this because when you lose focus on something it tends to become blurry.

No, I don't necessarily believe that my life would become easier if it was suddenly changed to `onFocusLost`.