# In web browsers, what's the difference between onblur and onfocusout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

If they're the same, then why there are two of this kind of event?

Comment: full explanation of event bubbling and capturing http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As you know, the **onBlur** event fires for an element if that element had the focus, but loses it.

The **onFocusOut** event fires in this case, but also triggers if any child element loses focus.

For example, you have a div with special formatting because the human is currently editing a field in that area.  You'd could use **onFocusOut** to turn that formatting off when focus leaves that div.

Up until very recently, **onFocusOut** was only used by IE.  If that has changed, it has been very recent.  Test in FF, Chrome, etc.

Comment: jan 2014 im using onfocusout in chrome

Comment: onBlur is fired even if the page loses focus

Comment: aug 2018, chrome, the `e.type` for jQuery on click handler for `blur` is `focusout` and not `blur`, i don't understand why.

Answer (score 12):

Acccording to the spec for the [focusout](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-focusout%20focusout) event type:

> This event type is similar to blur, but is dispatched before focus is shifted, and does bubble.

Whereas `blur` events do bubble, and are dispatched later.

Answer (score 5):

A litte demo. Notice that the parent div of focusin/focusout changes its color.

```css
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div onfocusin="this.style['background-color']='#efe'"
     onfocusout="this.style['background-color']='#eef'">
  <input onfocusin="this.value='focusin'" 
         onfocusout="this.value='focusout'"
         placeholder="focusin/focusout"/> bubbling (parent div receives event, too)
</div>

<div onfocus="this.style['background-color']='#efe'" 
     onblur="this.style['background-color']='#eef'">
  <input onfocus="this.value='focus'" 
         onblur="this.value='blur'"
         placeholder="focus/blur"/> not bubbling
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The focusout event fires when an element is about to lose focus.

The main difference between this event and blur is that focusout bubbles while blur does not. Most times, they can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

[The Jquery documentation has a good `focusout` vs. `blur` demo](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) which I'll reproduce below for clarity. In short, `focusout` fires if the selector — `$('p')` in the demo — is anything including the inputs and parent elements. Whereas, `blur` only fires if the selector is on the inputs — `$('input')`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>focusout demo</title>
  <style>
  .inputs {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
  .inputs p {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="inputs">
  <p>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="password">
  </p>
</div>
<div id="focus-count">focusout fire</div>
<div id="blur-count">blur fire</div>

<script>
var focus = 0,
  blur = 0;
$( "p" )
  .focusout(function() {
    focus++;
    $( "#focus-count" ).text( "focusout fired: " + focus + "x" );
  })
  .blur(function() {
    blur++;
    $( "#blur-count" ).text( "blur fired: " + blur + "x" );
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's essentially no difference in 2017:

https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

> Few web developers consciously use event capturing or bubbling. In Web pages as they are made today, it is simply not necessary to let a bubbling event be handled by several different event handlers. Users might get confused by several things happening after one mouse click, and usually you want to keep your event handling scripts separated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two differences:

1. `focusin/focusout` bubble, while `focus/blur` don't, and
2. `focusin/focusout` are fired just before the focus shift, while `focus/blur` happen after it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event