# OnFocusOut not working when UL loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

I can't seem, for the life of me, be able to figure as to why I cannot set the `$("#fileno_list").css("display", "none");` Ie. when the user hasn't quite made a selection and decides to click elsewhere on the page. Then the dropdown box should close. (display: none).

Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

Here's the code in Question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("#fileno_list ul").focusout(function() {

        $(this).css("display", "none");


    });



});

function test() {

var rs_count = 3

    if (rs_count > 1) {

        for (var x = 0; x < rs_count; ++x) {

            $("#fileno_list").append('<li>'+x+'</li>');

        }

        $("#fileno_arrow").css("display", "block");

    }

    $("#fileno_arrow").click(function() {

        $("#fileno_list").css("display", "block");

    });

    $("#fileno_list li").click(function(e) {

        var select = $(this).closest('#fileno_list')

        select.find(".selected").removeClass('selected');

        $(this).addClass('selected');

        $("#fileno").val(   $.trim( $(this).html()  )   )

        $("#fileno_list").css("display", "none");

    });

    $("#fileno").val( $("#fileno_list li").eq(0).html() )

}



</script>
```

Here is the HTML Markup:

```
<div class="field_container">

    <div class="field_wrapper"><input type="text" class="field" id="fileno"></div>

    <div id="fileno_arrow"></div>

    <ul id="fileno_list"></ul>


</div>
<br>
<br>

<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="click me">
<br>
```

Comment: `onfocusout` and `onblur` [are different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755052) and, just offhand, this looks like onblur would work here. Also, [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) that Firefox doesn't support onfocusout ... so what browser are you testing with?

Comment: This would be Internet Explorer 10

Comment: So... we have nested lists `<ul><li>  <ul>...</ul></li>` that make up some css driven multi-level drop-down menus that are enhanced with javascript, which gives us a similar situation... the menu stays open on a timer even if you mouse-away from it, but if you click away from it we close it immediately. In our case we just attach an _onclick_ handler to the `<body>` and do a `.removeClass('opened')` rather than act on focus events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your select tag has an id, you can use `event` object to check which element was clicked and show/hide based on that.

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id === "idOfSelect")
          $("#idOfSelect").show();
    });
```

Comment: This seems to address clicking _on_ the select list, but the question is about clicking _away_ from it and having it close because it lost focus.