# how can i set double attribute to one element?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi can I set 2 attributes to same element ?
I want to run 2 functions when I outfocus on one item ? any idea if not any alternative ? thanks.

```js
 listEl.setAttribute('onfocusout', `updateItem(${index}, ${row})`, 'onfocusout', `hideInputBoxOnElement(${row})`);
```

Comment: Set attribute only sets one attribute. You will need to use two calls (in this example it would only add 7 more characters) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: can you please elaborate more thanks. I want 2 things to happen after I onfouseout of the target element.

Comment: Check the first example in the link I posted

Comment: so I create a var selecting the button then var.setAttribute and double time the Attribute call..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for an event listener. Things like `onblur`, `onclick`, `onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, etc. are not attributes, but rather are inline event listeners that fire when that event occurs.

```js
//select the myElement somehow, either using the element's ID, class, etc.
myElement.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  updateItem(index, row);
  hideInputBoxOnElement(row);
});
```

You can have as many event listeners as you want in an element, so you can even do something like this:

```js
//select the myElement somehow, either using the element's ID, class, etc.
myElement.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  updateItem(index, row);
});

//select the myElement somehow, either using the element's ID, class, etc.
myElement.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  hideInputBoxOnElement(row);
});
```

Just a suggestion, you might want to use the `blur` event instead of the `focusout` event. What's the difference, you ask? [In web browsers, what's the difference between onblur and onfocusout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755052/in-web-browsers-whats-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onfocusout)
Basically, `focusout` is triggered when the element itself or any of its children lose focus, whereas `blur` only fires for the element itself.

It is often said that javascript event listeners that don't begin with the prefix `on-` is considered a better practice compared to starting with the prefix `on-`, but I personally don't think it makes much of a difference.

Comment: Ahhh I see what the op was asking now. Good spot

Comment: I updated the element variable name to not confuse things, and the event name should be `focusout`

Comment: thanks i used onblur as a second att and it worked did the job thanks endothermic_dragon